# In there any Dependencies Hierarchical view in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, dependencies, dependency-management

I used to use Eclipse and it has a view in which we can search a dependency and find different sources of it, and conclude the selected ones and the ommitted ones in case of conflicts.

Is there such in Intellij for an SBT project? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently sbt-dependency-graph is the wayh to go. There's an issue to improve this, please vote if you would like to increase its priority: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11038